# Creating a drag and drop with rangy

Tags: javascript, rangy

When I inspect my code it has the draggable attribute but the onDragStart is missing in the browser.

```
 rangy.createClassApplier(foo, {
        normalize: true,
        elementTagName: ‘mark’,
        elementProperties: {
          draggable: 'true',
          onDragStart: drag(event),
        },
    elementAttributes: {
     id: `drag${id}`,
    }
  }
```

On inspection this is what I see:

```
<mark id="drag2" draggable='true'>
here is some more
</mark>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Are you expecting to see the event handler auto created as an inline event handler? If so, I wouldn't worry or expect to see that. onDragStart will most likely be created in Javascript and not applied to the HTML as it is not needed and causes more issues than it solves.

Comment: expected: <mark id="drag2" draggable='true' ondragstart="drag(event)">
here is some more
</mark>

Comment: Is the function not working or you just expected to see the event handler added inline?

Comment: Both. The function is not working and the event is not inline. Here is the function:
```function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}```

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it isn't working because onDrag is not an element property but an event attribute, but I don't think rangy has eventAttribute as an option